# How to get exact ip address of client machin?

Tags: asp.net

I know REMOTE_ADDR returns the IP Address of the router and not the client user’s machine. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, since when client user is behind a proxy server his machine’s IP Address the Proxy Server’s IP Address is appended to the client machine’s IP Address. If client machine is behind many proxy server, all server id is appended to it. But I want only client machine address.

How to get that?

```
 string ipaddress;
 ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
 if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
    ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Will the following code return the ipaddress of client or local machine?

```
ipaddress = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrieve the Name of HOST
IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ipaddress);

IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

string ip = addr[2].ToString();
```

or shall I go for this

```
 private string GetUserIP()
 {
        string ipList = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipList))
        {
            return ipList.Split(',')[0];
        }

        return Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

to fetch first one?

Comment: "If client machine is behind many proxy server,all server id is appended to it" - only if they're configured to "be nice". It's not guaranteed. There's no guaranteed way to find an IP address that is in use within the network stack of the client's machine, nor would it generally be useful (e.g. in a lot of circumstances, lot's of machines will be using the *same* IP addresses within the private use spaces of Ipv4)

Comment: @JuiTest It would be more helpful if you explain what you are going to use the client-ip for. Generally speaking you can't route to it from your webservice, so it's really only usable for logging (and even there it is of limited benefit). What's your use case?

Comment: @RB,thanks for ur reply.I want to know ip from where request came.I am using web application.I am using web page as api.User can call page directly no need to login.

Comment: @JuiTest RB said "logging" not "log in". Meaning creating a record of which IP addresses have accessed the site and when. Is that what you want to do? Anyway as Damien points out if the client machine is behind a firewall or NAT router or anything like that you won't get the original IP, just the IP of the last gateway it went through. And it wouldn't be much use if you did - right now you'd get 192.168.0.11 as my IP if you got my real one. But you can't ping that on the net, and there are probably 20 million other machines out there with the same IP. Read up on NAT if you want to understand.

Comment: @JuiTest Please clarify *why* you want the client IP - what are you going to use it for?

Comment: @Rb,thanks for ur reply.I want to store it in my database.

Comment: @JuiTest Yes, but WHY?!!! What are you ultimately going to use this information for? What is it's purpose? If you didn't have this information, what in your application would stop working?

Comment: @Rb,thanks for ur reply.I don't have this info.It was told to me that save ipaddress in database in order to find out from where request is comomg.I modified my code pls go through it.